# Direct file access in C++?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

Are there way to write directly to disk without cache in c++?
Currently I am using:

```
int open(fileout, O_CREATE | O_WRONLY | O_DIRECT);  
FILE *fh = fdopen(fileout_dev, "wb");
```

Are there cross platform libraries allowing to do that?

Thanks Arman.

Comment: Are you asking about defeating cacheing in the operating system or in the C/C++ RTL?

Comment: Or in the hard disk controller?

Comment: I would like to write to file without caching...

Comment: And we ask what kind of caching you want to avoid. There are many levels. Some can be avoided in the language, some is OS dependent, some requires access to the hardware. Or the network server, if the file resides there.

Comment: BTW IO through your `FILE *fh` opened with `O_DIRECT` like you did is also buffered within FILE object - unless you cancel buffering like @RC suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about buffering, then you can use [setbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setbuf/) or [setvbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/)

```
/* setbuf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer[BUFSIZ];
  FILE *pFile1, *pFile2;

  pFile1=fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
  pFile2=fopen ("myfile2.txt","a");

  setbuf ( pFile1 , buffer );
  fputs ("This is sent to a buffered stream",pFile1);
  fflush (pFile1);

  setbuf ( pFile2 , NULL );
  fputs ("This is sent to an unbuffered stream",pFile2);

  fclose (pFile1);
  fclose (pFile2);

  return 0;
}


/* setvbuf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *pFile;

  pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","w");

  // _IONBF disables buffering
  setvbuf (pFile , NULL , _IONBF, 0);

  // File operations here

  fclose (pFile);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it same as O_DIRECT?

Comment: @Arman: BTW O_DIRECT doesn't guarantee you don't have caching. It just requests Unix-like kernel to not cache IO though this FD. Hardware itself may be caching internally.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. With my RAIDS6(LVM/STRIPED/with 2RAID Controllers) I get 1200MB/s when I do dd oflag=direct, without I get less than 500, I can see the large files are going over the cache during the copy, so to speedup IO I was trying to implement im my code some DIRECT_IO